# Call form submit action from php function on same page

Tags: php, html, forms, webforms

I'm working on a simple web application. In order to reduce the number of files, I want to put (php) code for a  form submit function into the same page as the form. Something like this:

```
<body>
   <form id = "rsvp-status-form" action = "rsvpsubmit" method = "post">
     <input type="radio" name="rsvp-radio" value="yes"/> Yes<br/>
     <input type="radio" name="ravp-radio" value="no" checked/> No<br/>
     <input type="radio" name="rsvp-radio" value="notsure"/> Not Sure<br/>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
   </form>
 </body>

<?php 
  function rsvpsubmit() {
    // do stuff here
  }
```

What is the proper way to call the submit function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you fix your radio group so they all have the same name:

```
if (isset($_POST['rsvp-radio'])) {
    rsvpsubmit();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['rsvpsubmit'])) {
     //do something
     rsvpsubmit();
   }
   else {
    //show form
?>
<body>
   <form id="rsvp-status-form" action="?rsvpsubmit" method="post">
      <input type="radio" name="rsvp-radio" value="yes"/> Yes<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="rsvp-radio" value="no" checked/> No<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="rsvp-radio" value="notsure"/> Not Sure<br/>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
   </form>
 </body>
<?php 
  }

  function rsvpsubmit() {
    // do stuff here
  }
?>
```

Comment: The form method is POST, so checking $_GET will not have the desired effect.